# Are "go into," "come into," and "get into" transitive?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

As the subject says. Note the following sentences:

"I got into a taxi."
"He came into the room."
"We went into the store."

For some reason, I have always been under the impression that locations in sentences like these are not considered direct objects. To my mind, these are different than sentences such as "The truck crashed into the store" or "He blew up the car." I can't explain why, however. Or am I wrong altogether on this one?

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: None of the examples you cite contain a transitive verb.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/get) describes these senses as "no object, with adverbial of direction". Whether you consider them transitive seems to depend on your definition of transitivity, which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivity_(grammar)) suggests is debated, and can be viewed semantically or grammatically.

Comment: I think of the taxi and the store to be objects of a preposition.  So they have a bit of an object feel so I can understand your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Passive Test. Almost all transitive clauses allow the Passive transformation, which promotes direct objects to subject position, adds an auxiliary *be*, changes the main verb form, and demotes the agent -- but doesn't change the meaning:

- *Bill ate the last banana.* == Passive => *The last banana was eaten by Bill.*

For the three sentences given, Passive would work like this (with modifications to make Passive easier):

- *Frank got into the taxi.*  == Passive =>  **The taxi was got(ten) into by Frank*
- *Mary came into the room.*  == Passive =>  **The room was come into by Mary*
- *The twins went into the store.*  == Passive =>  **The store was gone into by the twins*

As can be seen, the putative passive transforms are ungrammatical,
showing that these are not transitive sentences with direct objects.

Answer (score 0):

A direct object is one which directly receives the action of the subject: *I hit the ball; He blew up the car;* even *They entered the building.*

Your example sentences use the preposition *into.* What follows *into* is a *prepositional object:*

> The prepositional object is the noun or pronoun that the preposition affects or describes. So, if you were to say “the apple in the tree,” the word *in* is the preposition and *tree* is **its** object. The full prepositional phrase modifies *apple* by telling us where it is.
>
> [Grammarbook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/prepositions/object-of-a-preposition) (my emphasis)

Note that *the building* is not the direct object in "They went into the building": the verb *go* (along with others like *come*) is not a transitive verb and can never take an object — which is why a prepositional phrase is necessary.

*Get* is a versatile verb which **can** take an object in its "obtain" meaning: "She got an apple". But it doesn't take an object in other uses, and certainly doesn't when it's followed by a prepositional phrase.

Comment: When the verb is better considered unary rather than a **V**simplex **+ Prep** construction, most would call the unary verb (traditionally 'phrasal verb' etc; after many more modern analysts, 'multi-word verbs') 'transitive' where appropriate. (a) He *came round* about thirty minutes after knocking himself out. [*come round* = *regain consciousness* an intransitive MWV] // (b1) She's *come across* a novel solution to the Heinz paradox. [*come across* = *hit upon / discover* a transitive MWV] // (b2) He's *come down with* Covid. [*come down with* = *contract / fall ill with* a transitive MWV]

Comment: @Edwin If your comment is disagreeing with my answer (I can't actually tell) then please write an answer.

Comment: No; it's going on to consider the identical-looking cases where [V + prep/part] are considered a MWV, which is usually considered intransitive or transitive according to whether the particle is a transitivising particle.

Comment: Well if you think my answer is incomplete, please write another.

Comment: I can't without duplicating your answer, for then my answer would be incomplete. But I'm sure that the distinction between obliques and direct objects has been covered here in greater depth before.

Comment: So basically you're saying that *blow up* is a "multi-word verb". I think I've said (ok, maybe implied) that in the first paragraph.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - It's up to you, but when I have something to contribute that's a little more than a comment, but not quite an answer, I write a *supplementary answer.*

Comment: Yes, Andrew ... but if an answer is required here, I think it better to put forward that 'blow up' is a verb (a MWV) here. The concept of two-orthographic-word words is far from basic. // @
aparente001 I would do, but I can remember all this as having being covered here before. The [MWV + DO] ... [Vsimplex + PP] continuum. And the notion of 'oblique objects'.